# distance formula in python bug

Tags: python, distance, formula

I'm calculating the length of a line segment in python, but I don't understand why one piece of code gives me zero and the other gives the right answer.

This piece of code gives me zero:

```
def distance(a, b):
    y = b[1]-a[1]
    x = b[0]-a[0]
    ans=y^2+x^2
    return ans^(1/2)
```

This one gives me the right answer:

```
import math as math

def distance(a, b):
    y = b[1]-a[1]
    x = b[0]-a[0]
    ans=y*y+x*x
    return math.sqrt(ans)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using the `^` operator?  What do you think that operator does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your first snippet you have written this:

```
ans^(1/2)
```

In Python the power operator is **not** `^`, that's the **XOR**-operator. The power operator in Python is `**`. On top of that, in Python 2.x by default the result of the division of two integers is an integer, so `1/2` will evaluate as `0`. The correct way would be this:

```
ans ** 0.5
```

And another thing, the function you have implemented here can be done a lot easier with [**`math.hypot`**](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.hypot):

```
import math

def distance(a, b):
    return math.hypot(b[0] - a[0], b[1] - a[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `x**2` rather than `x^2` ( which is XOR)

Or use the `math.pow` function

And also, `1/2` is 0 and not `0.5`